# Which <meta> tags are useful and which not?

Tags: html, xhtml, seo

How many total `<meta>` tags are available in X/HTML and which should be used and which not? Are there any pros to using meta tags other than the meta description?

note: Google doesn't give any importance to meta keywords.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of SEO, the **description** meta tag is what most search engines will usually show in search results, so that's quite important.

Google have said that they don't use the **keywords** tag at all. And the other searches engines value it very little, if at all.

The **robots** tag can be useful if you want to stop SEs indexing certain pages, but using robots.txt is the better option. Certainly, don't bother with "positive" instructions like `INDEX, FOLLOW` because that's what SEs do by default anyway.

The **language** and **content type** tags are best replaced with HTTP headers if you have that option. Same goes for caching, revisit-after etc but I'm not sure any browsers take note of that anyway.

Don't bother with the meta tags that relate to "creation" (i.e. **author**, **copyright**, **generator** and so on) unless you have a specific use for them.

Comment: A decade after this answer was written, the meta description is no longer very important either.  It used to be shown frequently in the search results, but it is now shown a small fraction of the time.  These days even the meta description is an optional meta tag for SEO.

Answer (score -1):

First of all meta **description** and then **language** and **robots**.

You may also need **verify-v1** temporarily when you are validating against http://www.google.com/webmasters

Edit: The robots tag is a SEO "tool" which can let you fine tune how the robots operate on your website. Language allows you to state the language in which the page is written in.

Comment: what is the benefit to use language and robots

Answer (score -2):

> Which  tags are useful and which
> not?

*All* mega tags are useful, it is just that *you use them when you need them*. Also the link you provided does not say anything about usefulness or drawbacks or meta tags.

Use only those meta tags that you need, don't add not needed tags to your pages. This also makes page messy and longer to load.

Comment: No they aren't. The Meta Revisit After tag is one example.